# Forced movement into danger: is there a saving throw?

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement, saving-throw

Is there a saving throw to stop forced movement (a push, pull, or slide) from forcing you into a square that will damage you?

My wizard's tactic lately has been to try to *Thunderwave* enemies into the *Wall of Fire*. My DM gave the enemies a chance to save from entering the wall because it would cause them damage. I can't find anything under the forced movement section that says that except for "Catching yourself" which refers to the Falling section (PHB p 284) where it says

> ...if a power or bull rush forces you
>   over a precipice or into a pit, you
>   can immediately make a saving throw to
>   avoid going over the edge.

Did I miss the rule she's using? If there is no other rule, why is falling treated different? (i.e. what makes a character grab at the edge of the pit more effectively than at the edge of a wall of fire?)

Granted, she did apply the same rule when we were getting pushed around into a pool of acid a while ago, so either way she's applying it fairly.

Answer (score 18):

From the DMG/Compendium, the important part for your question:

> Forced Movement and Terrain
>
> Difficult Terrain: Forced movement
>   isn’t hindered by difficult terrain.
>
> Blocking Terrain: Forced movement
>   can’t move a creature through blocking
>   terrain (page 61). Every square along
>   the path must be a space the creature
>   could normally occupy.
>
> Challenging Terrain: Forced movement
>   can make some powers more effective or
>   hinder them, depending on the specific
>   challenging terrain. The DM can
>   require the target of forced movement
>   to make a check as if it were moving
>   voluntarily across the terrain, with
>   the same consequence for failure.
>
> Hindering Terrain: Forced movement can
>   force targets into hindering terrain.
>   Targets forced into hindering terrain
>   receive a saving throw immediately
>   before entering the unsafe square they
>   are forced into. Success leaves the
>   target prone at the edge of the square
>   before entering the unsafe square. If
>   the power that forced the target to
>   move allows the creature that used the
>   power to follow the target into the
>   square that the target would have
>   left, the creature can’t enter the
>   square where the target has fallen
>   prone. If forced movement pushes a
>   Large or larger creature over an edge,
>   the creature doesn’t fall until its
>   entire space is over the edge. On the
>   creature’s next turn, it must either
>   move to a space it can occupy or use a
>   move action to squeeze into the
>   smaller space at the edge of the
>   precipice.
>
> A DM can allow a power that pushes a
>   target more than 1 square to carry the
>   target completely over hindering
>   terrain.
>
> Published in Dungeon Master's Guide.

And from the DnD FAQ ( http://wizards.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/wizards.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=1396 ):

> Are zones that deal damage (like the Wizard power Stinking Cloud) considered ‘hindering terrain’? Can I make a save to fall prone and avoid being forced into one?
>
> No, zones are not considered hindering terrain.  Hindering terrain refers to more permanent features like pits, cliffs or pools of lava.

The resultant answer:  For zones, base DnD rules do not give a saving throw to avoid being put into the fire.  For pools of acid, you are given a saving throw to catch yourself before it and fall prone.

Answer (score 6):

Your tactic is legal and should be allowed.

Here is a good [summary](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19685882/Consolidated_Customer_Service_Answers?post_id=366394349#366394349) of some recent answers from WoTC Customer service.  It is still an open question if you can cause a target to take damage multiple times by sliding them in and out of a zone.  (Obviously thunder wave can't be used this way, but other abilities can).

Comment: FWIW, if you're pushing your thunderwave victim along the edge of a zone you can push them diagonally in and out and in and out. But it doesn't come up that often.