# What is hindering terrain?

Tags: dnd-4e

In [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/2905/8) about forced movement into dangerous spaces, an answer refers to "hindering terrain", which is a category I haven't seen before. It included a quote from a WotC faq that stated

> Hindering terrain refers to more
>   permanent features like pits, cliffs
>   or pools of lava.

What is the full definition? Where is it defined?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hindering terrain** is defined in the new ***Rules Compendium (207)***.  It is terrain that punishes creatures for entering/being in them.

The examples of hindering terrain are pits, electrifying runes, lava and deep water.

*A creature can make a saving throw when it is pulled, pushed, slid, or teleported into hindering terrain.*

In short, hindering terrain is whatever the DM or module says is hindering terrain.  When a DM describes the battlefield to the players he should be explicit as to which terrain that they can see is hindering.

- Zones are not hindering terrain.
- Cliffs are not
  hindering terrain.  Forced movement
  grants a saving throw if the target
  is forced over a precipice **or** into hindering terrain (Rules Compendium p212).

An earlier definition of Hindering Terrain is in the ***Dungeon Masters Guide p61.***  That definition says that Hindering Terrain prevents movement or severely punishes it.  Preventing movement is no longer part of the definition of Hindering Terrain.  Preventing movement is handled under **Blocking Terrain**.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably add gimmicky teleports to the list of pseudo-hindering terrain. I teleport you 6 squares straight up? Lets roll a save first.

Anything that either does massive damage (ie more damage than a daily, ie lava, drowning, etc) or instantly removes/reduces a creatures ability to fight by a massive margin (consider a pit more as soemthing that would require a minute and maybe some help to get out of, removing a creature for a minute from combat is amazing for a power rather than a pit trap).

Comment: p213 of the Rules Compendium - if arriving in the destination space would cause the target to fall **or** if that space is hindering terrain.