# How many squares of forced movement are required to push something into a Wall of Fire?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizard, forced-movement

The Wall of Fire specifies that 3 extra squares of movement (for a total of 4 squares) are required to enter a wall of fire.  Does this apply to forced movement?

Typically, forced movement ignores difficult or hindering terrain.  However, neither of these terms is used in the Wall of Fire power.

Comment: You can use forced movement to move a creature into hindering terrain.  They do get a saving throw though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some pondering I think Brian's [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3450/wall-of-fire-how-often-can-a-creature-be-damaged/3455#3455) is correct.

Forced movement should pay the extra +3 for each square of the [Wall of Fire](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=722) entered.

The *Rules Compendium* covers Forced Movement on pages 211-213.  It notes that difficult terrain is ignored.  No mention is made of [hindering terrain](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/what-is-hindering-terrain).  The section on hindering terrain (p207) notes that you get a saving throw if you are push/pull/slide/teleported into it.

Comment: ::nod:: extra movement cost doesn't equate to hindering terrain.

Comment: @Iszi Correct on all points.

Comment: Removed earlier comment due to some inaccuracy - the issue of whether a Wall of Fire does or does not constitute hindering terrain, is still the subject of some debate.  Still, it is agreed that the +3 movement penalty should apply to forced movement into a Wall of Fire.