# When do attack powers that do multiple repeat attacks in the power actually "resolve"?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, attack

I have a polearm Eladrin fighter that is all about multiple attacks, so I have powers like Tempest Dance and Serpent Dance Strike. I just leveled to EPIC and I found 2 feats that I'd like to take, but I'm curious how they would work together, Mobile Warrior and Feywild Warrior.

Using Tempest Dance and Feywild Warrior as an example, the way it reads, you do your attack against a target. Then it's effect is that you can shift 1 and repeat the attack against  a second target, then shift 1 square and repeat the attack against the third target.
Feywild Warrior says when I hit with a martial daily attack power I can teleport myself and the target 5 squares "after you resolve the attack".

So, How I'm thinking this could work is, I activate my Tempest Dance power while in reach of a monster. I attack it, hit it, then teleport it and myself 5 squares. Then I shift 1 and repeat the attack against a second monster, and if I hit, I can teleport myself and that monster 5 squares. Then shift 1 and attack a third monster, hit it, and teleport it 5 squares.

Or, it could work like this, I activate the power, attack, hit, then shift 1, attack, hit, shift 1, attack, hit, THEN teleport me and that last monster I hit 5 squares after the whole power resolves.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6):

### Successive attacks resolve individually within their power.

**Yes, you can teleport after each hit and continue the attack**, as long as you can make a valid successive attack from your new position.

In contrast to area attacks, which are all rolled at once, successive attacks (in the form of powers like *tempest dance* or others, such as a successive claw/claw/bite in a monster's stat block) each resolve separately and can be separately responded to. The Rules Compendium, for example, explicitly states on p.196 that you can use an immediate reaction in response to a claw that lets you shift away from the followup claw and bite attacks.

Comment: I had another thought while talking to my DM about this, since I'm an Eladrin, and I have some of the Eladrin items on like the boots and chainmail armor, which gives me a bonus to my teleport, does that apply to the teleport from the Feywild Warrior for both me and my target? Does it apply to just me? Do I get the bonus and my target does not?

Comment: Just you. There are other items that increase the distance you teleport other creatures.

Comment: 1 last question, since it doesn't specify that we need to end up adjacent to each other, could I teleport the creature to 1 spot and teleport myself to another spot nowhere near it? I would assume yes, but I'd just like to make sure, since the feat's wording kind of implies that I'm teleporting and taking the creature with me.

Comment: Doesn't say the creature has to wind up adjacent to you or as near to you as possible or anything. You could, if you wanted, skip around the battlefield and teleport everything into a nice tight cluster for the warlock to drop an area burst 1 on. Just remember that teleporting something so that it falls or enters hindering terrain gives it a save to avoid the effect.

Comment: That was my plan, to use the attack shift attack shift attack fighter dailies to teleport a bunch of the enemies into a nice little bundle for the AE burster. Thanks! That's interesting, I didn't know about the save to avoid the teleport if the destination is difficult terrain. And since I'm an Eladrin with some of the Eladrin items, that teleport 5 becomes a teleport 10 for me (I'm missing the ring).

Comment: Not difficult terrain. On its own that's fine. Hindering terrain is map hazards that hurt or imperil you for being there. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/what-is-hindering-terrain

Comment: Oh ok, I for some reason I equated hindering with difficult terrain.