# Is teleporting a creature considered forced movement of said creature?

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement, teleportation

Is teleporting a creature considered to be forced movement of said creature? I have a player interested in a power that adds damage on forced movement and teleport.

Comment: Damage and teleportation related: [Forced movement into danger: is there a saving throw?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2905/forced-movement-into-danger-is-there-a-saving-throw?rq=1)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. From the compendium:

> **Forced Movement**
>
> Movement that a creature is compelled to do, specifically a pull, a push, or a slide. A creature can be moved in other ways, such as through teleportation, but only pulls, pushes, and slides are technically forced movement.

Answer (score 5):

It's not forced movement, but per [the Player's Handbook errata](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/UpdatePH.pdf), trying to teleport creatures into dangerous terrain or to a spot where they will fall gives them an immediate saving throw to avoid the teleport.

> #### Teleportation
>
> **Page 286:** Replace the text for the Destination entry 
>   and the Immobilized entry. This change addresses 
>   what happens when a creature is forced to teleport, 
>   and it clarifies that the Immobilized entry includes 
>   restrained as well.
>
> ✦ **Destination:** Your destination must be a space you 
>   can occupy without squeezing. If arriving in the 
>   destination space would cause the target to fall or if 
>   that space is hindering terrain, the target can make a 
>   saving throw. On a save, the teleportation is negated.

Comment: A comment on the question with a link to [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2905/forced-movement-into-danger-is-there-a-saving-throw?rq=1) could have been enough.