# Can you teleport a monster vertically up and thus damage them when they fall?

Tags: dnd-4e, teleportation, damage

Can you teleport a monster vertically up and thus do them the D10 per 10' falling damage?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes, but they get a saving throw.**

Teleporting them in the air counts as teleporting them into potentially damaging terrain, therefore they get a save. A successful save negates the teleport.

[Hindering Terrain](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=540):

> A type of terrain that hinders creatures, usually by damaging them. Examples: Pits, lava, and deep water. A creature can make a saving throw when it is pulled, pushed, slid, or teleported into hindering terrain. See also teleportation.

Answer (score 16):

Yes. From the compendium:

> **Teleportation**
>
> **Irrelevant rules snipped**
>
> If arriving in the destination space would cause the target to fall or if that space is hindering terrain, the target can immediately make a saving throw. On a save, the teleportation is negated. Otherwise, the target arrives in the destination space.

Afterwards, normal rules for falling would apply.

Comment: Note that the brevity of this answer is not to be taken condescendingly, but to match my answer to [your other question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13481/1069) earlier today ;)